# query on two columns in spring data cassandra

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I have three columns in my cassandra table (A,B,C).
A -- PARTITIONED key,
B -- CLUSTERED key

I want to query on A in "list I will pass" and B -- one value.
I don't want to use @query (want to use something like findAll())

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options for now:

1. Using `CassandraTemplate` or `CqlTemplate`, passing in a `Select` you built yourself.
2. Wait until [DATACASS-7](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-7) is resolved (under review now) and use the repository abstraction with `findByAIndAndB(Collection<String> aValues, String bValue)`. Expect a milestone-release right before August.

Comment: thanks man , But as@jny mentioned in the below comment , I don't think it is good practice to write queries like this. Don't I have any other option ?

Comment: can you guys assist me with , how to use CassandraTemplate  in this ?

Comment: @Jitender_Yadav take a look here: https://gist.github.com/mp911de/a5f26274272da3c3de051a8fd55a62f4

Answer (score 1):

I have not looked at Cassandra in a while, I believe it is not a good practice to run queries like this, especially if partition keys reside on different nodes. It is  a lot more efficient to run a separate query on each partition key and then merge the results.